# Why doesn't Ctrl+Alt+Del work in KDE when set as a shortcut for Log Out?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, shortcut-keys

In KDE, I have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> specified as shortcut for `Log Out` in KDE Session Manager, but once I press it - nothing happens.

The same happens with `Log Out Without Confirmation` and other shortcuts.

How to fix it?

P.S. Restarting KDE Session (or even rebooting PC) does not help.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the shortcuts from before an upgrade, I noticed that the key shortcuts changed from <kbd>ctrl</kbd> to something like <kbd>primary</kbd> and <kbd>secondary</kbd>, to support right and left ctrl shortcuts.

Try changing the keypress, and use the option to press the keys to get the shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

There are two Log Outs, one in Run Command Interface, and the other in The KDE Session Manager. In my computer, it won't work if you assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> to the former. So may it work if you assign to the later.